# get the values from a text box after releasing the field

Tags: jquery, html

As i am new to jquery, i don't know what exactly i do here,

I have a form call it as frmCustom, and have three text boxes

```
 <form id="frmCustom">

       <input type="text" id="width">
       <input type="text" id="height">
       <input type="text" id="depth">

    </form>
```

i just want to get the three values inside the text boxes immediately after entering using jquery

any help will be appreciable,

thanks in advance

Comment: <<get the values from a text box after releasing the field>> <<i just want to get the three values inside the text boxes immediately after entering>> Is the same behaviour you are describing here? I dont' get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the .change event:

```
$('#frmCustom input[type="text"]').change(function () {
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
    var depth = $('#depth').val();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Bryrt/3/

```
$('#frmCustom input').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id')== 'width') 
        var w = $(this).val();
    if($(this).attr('id')== 'height') 
        var h = $(this).val();
    if($(this).attr('id')== 'depth') 
        var d = $(this).val();

    alert([w,h,d]);
});
```

Comment: This answer is near to my needs, Instead of appending onto a div can you assign each text box value to a variable?   something like  var width=$(width).val,

Comment: you mean this? check my update answer, alert is to see the variables value. You will get the each value one buy one as soon as user enters.